# Extract text between HTML tags (<tr> </tr>)

Tags: html, perl, parsing

I'm trying to extract the text between all `<tr> </tr>` tags in a string and print them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $HTML = '
<tr data_1="15,12,2016" data_2="1">
<td class="cl_1">11111</td>
<td class="cl_2">11111</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>11111</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">11111</td>
</tr>
<tr data_1="16,12,2016" data_2="0">
<td class="cl_1">22222</td>
<td class="cl_2">22222</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>22222</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">22222</td>
</tr>
<tr data_1="15,12,2016" data_2="1">
<td class="cl_1">33333</td>
<td class="cl_2">33333</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>33333</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">33333</td>
</tr>
';

while($HTML =~ /data_2="1">(.*)<\/tr>(\R)/sg) {
    print "$1\n\n";
}
```

The output should be:

```
<td class="cl_1">11111</td>
<td class="cl_2">11111</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>11111</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">11111</td>

<td class="cl_1">33333</td>
<td class="cl_2">33333</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>33333</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">33333</td>
```

How do I do that and extract the content from each `<tr>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing answer to include new restriction on which `<tr>'s` are wanted

```
my $HTML = '
<tr data_1="15,12,2016" data_2="1">
<td class="cl_1">11111</td>
<td class="cl_2">11111</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>11111</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">11111</td>
</tr>
<tr data_1="16,12,2016" data_2="0">
<td class="cl_1">22222</td>
<td class="cl_2">22222</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>22222</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">22222</td>
</tr>
<tr data_1="15,12,2016" data_2="1">
<td class="cl_1">33333</td>
<td class="cl_2">33333</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>33333</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">33333</td>
</tr>
';

while($HTML =~ /<tr[^>]*data_2=\"1\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/tr>/msg) {
    print "$1\n\n"; }
```

Output:

```
<td class="cl_1">11111</td>
<td class="cl_2">11111</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>11111</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">11111</td>

<td class="cl_1">33333</td>
<td class="cl_2">33333</td>
<td class="cl_3"><strong>33333</strong></td>
<td class="cl_4" colspan="3">33333</td>
```

Comment: The output is not wrong, because I need to extract only the content from <tr> tags that contains `data_2="0"`

Comment: I guess that I do not see that anywhere in the question.  Also,  do you mean that you want `data_2="1"`?   That would seem to better match your proposed output

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I mean data_2="1"

Comment: Changed to match additional restriction

Comment: Where is the parsing-HTML-with-regex police?